# Локализация string из public interface

Tags: java, android, интерфейс

Есть библиотека для обрезки изображений.
У неё есть код вида:

```
@Override
public void onPicModeSelected(String mode) {
    String action = mode.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.PicModes.CAMERA) ? Constants.IntentExtras.ACTION_CAMERA : Constants.IntentExtras.ACTION_GALLERY;
    actionProfilePic(action);
}
```

У пользователя строится диалог с выбором: Сфотографировать или же Выбрать из Галереи.

Этот текст (тот, который высвечивается в Диалоге) написан вот в таком классе:

```
public class Constants {



public interface IntentExtras {
    String ACTION_CAMERA = "action-camera";
    String ACTION_GALLERY = "action-gallery";
    String IMAGE_PATH = "image-path";
}

public interface PicModes {

    String CAMERA = "Сфотографировать";
    String GALLERY = "Выбрать из Галереи";

}
```

}

Я сейчас перевожу приложение на английский, поэтому хотел бы перевести эти 2 String на английский, если таковой установлен у пользователя.

Как это сделать?

Comment: У Вас есть возможность изменять исходный код библиотеки?

Comment: Я не знаю. Как таковые это просто импортированные классы. Возможно, можно изменить что-то в onPicModeSelected ?